# what is the difference between allowed_hosts and cors_origin_regex_whitelist in django?

Tags: django, gunicorn, devops

What is the difference between this two django settings :

- `ALLOWED_HOSTS`
- `CORS_ORIGIN_REGEX_WHITELIST`

Answer (score 2):

`ALLOWED_HOSTS`

> A list of strings representing the host/domain names that this Django site can serve. This is a security measure to prevent HTTP Host header attacks, which are possible even under many seemingly-safe web server configurations

`CORS_ORIGIN_REGEX_WHITELIST`

This is actually a variable expecting a third party package `django-cors-headers`.So the thing is when a browser starts a request through javascript to another domain (cross domain), browser will send a `OPTIONS` request first to get to know whether server is `allowing` the domain to accept request by checking `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

**Note**

There are some other headers also using this like `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` , etc.

Answer (score 0):

[`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) as the docs say is

> A list of strings representing the host/domain names that this Django
>   site can serve.

So, if `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.mysite.com', 'mysite.com']` and you try to access from your browser `blog.mysite.com` then Django will be unable to serve this page. You should `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.mysite.com', 'mysite.com', 'blog.mysite.com']` Read the docs related to `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. They are pretty straightforward!

[`CORS_ORIGIN_REGEX_WHITELIST`](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers#cors_origin_whitelist) as the docs say (again):

> A list of regexes that match origin regex list of origin hostnames
>   that are authorized to make cross-site HTTP requests.

This setting is most used when you have an API that exposes some endpoints for clients to consume. It allows browser's requests to these URLs patterns. So, if `CORS_ORIGIN_REGEX_WHITELIST = [r'images.mysite.com', ]` then the `<img src="http://images.mysite.com/image.jpg />"` will load successfully, but if `<img src="http://big-images.mysite.com/image.jpg />"` then it would fail.

More about CORS in [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).